# What's happening with this DBI:db object when errstr is called?

Tags: perl, reference, moose

I'm delegating an attribute in my current class called 'dbc' as a DBIx::Connector so that I can call $self->dbc->dbh from inside methods, however I'm not really understanding some behaviors I'm seeing when calling the 'errstr' method on the DBI::db instance:

This:

```
eval {
    $dbh->do($sql);
};

$self->log->warn("Warning SQL error: $dbh->errstr") if ($@);
```

returns `WARN - Warning SQL error: DBI::db=HASH(0xaf43130)->errstr`

However, this works, and returns a proper error string:

```
eval {
        $dbh->do($sql);
    };

    if($@){
        my $errstr = $dbh->errstr;
        $self->log->warn("Warning SQL error: $errstr");
    }
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl doesn't interpolate method calls inside double-quoted strings.  `$dbh->errstr` is calling a method.  Try:

```
$self->log->warn("Warning SQL error: " . $dbh->errstr) if $@;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to interpolate a function call in a string.

Try concatenating the warning string with function call.

```
$self->log->warn("Warning SQL error: ".$dbh->errstr) if ($@);
```

This part of the error:
    DBI::db=HASH(0xaf43130)

is the address of the db handle.